# How to use bitcoinj to transfer btc from p2sh-p2wpkh

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, raw-transaction, bitcoinj

I wrote the code for transmitting btc from p2sh-p2wpkh based on the information I found, but when I tried to broadcast the original transaction in https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/pushtx/, an exception occurred and the exception message was :

```
Error validating transaction: Error running script for input 0 referencing 
f6ff7b391590c3c161f012e7313c9bd7379846a209219a4722cb8864190466ae at 0: Script was NOT verified successfully..
```

This is my broadcast data:

```
01000000000101ae6604196488cb22479a2109a2469837d79b3c31e712f061c1c39015397bfff600000000160014208a8852a3cec93382c8bebbbd6c9ef4676f5120ffffffff02a08601000000000017a9141f396a0c4994cae1820224bb249a21de3ad4e73287acfd13000000000017a91466e9ecd8e67b63a4022f0420f772a070fa7d6e608702483045022100f3e5b7483760ff764b5a7620ba341499ec41c5b2fd67917bfef233b547f6e5e7022071b3f96e9c1d271b723f161a7a0aeafddef16aeb053fe2b443c0e4d31a785a7a012103ca65ac405e0ea1b514c61b797035674a27457fea63a8972cd473eef05871247400000000
```

I have checked a lot of information, but I can't find the problem. I hope to get help!

The test method I executed:
https://github.com/lingting/VirtualCurrency/blob/0.3.4/src/test/java/live/lingting/virtual/currency/omni/Transfer.java#L387

I signed the p2sh-p2wpkh address processing code:
https://github.com/lingting/VirtualCurrency/blob/0.3.4/src/main/java/live/lingting/virtual/currency/service/impl/BtcOmniServiceImpl.java#L414

```
// Custom redemption script
Script redeemScript = new ScriptBuilder().smallNum(0).data(keys.get(0).getPubKeyHash()).build();
TransactionSignature signature;
signature = tx.calculateWitnessSignature(inputIndex, key, redeemScript, txIn.getValue(), SigHash.ALL,false);
txIn.setScriptSig(redeemScript);
// p2sh-p2wpkh 设置 witness
txIn.setWitness(TransactionWitness.redeemP2WPKH(signature, keys.get(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

solved

```
Script redeemScript = ScriptBuilder.createP2WPKHOutputScript(key);

Script witnessScript = ScriptBuilder.createP2PKHOutputScript(key);

TransactionSignature signature = tx.calculateWitnessSignature(inputIndex, key, witnessScript, txIn.getValue(), SigHash.ALL,
        false);

txIn.setWitness(TransactionWitness.redeemP2WPKH(signature, key));
txIn.setScriptSig(new ScriptBuilder().data(redeemScript.getProgram()).build());
```